# How to construct a REST API that takes an array of id's for the resources in expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

in my MongoDB schema, I have an attr like this

```
. . . . 
 tags: [{ type: String, required: true }],
. . . . .
```

I want to retrieve all the collections when a user requests multiple tags. How can I construct such an endpoint with mongoose and express it in nodejs

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

so your rest endpoint could take input from the body as

a hypothetical endpoint would be : GET /students/tags

```
const {tags} = req.body;

{
  "tags": ["sports" , "eca"]
}

syntax:
<collectionName>.find( { tags: [<tag1>, <tag2>] } )

eg:    
student.find( { tags: ["sports", "eca"] } ) //it would be in order
student.find( { tags: { $eq: [ "sports", "eca" ] } } ) // if its equal to the required and irrespective of order  

student.find( { tags: { $eq: tags } } ) // destructured req.body
```

[Query An Array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element)
[Equality Operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#examples)

Comment: thanks, but how can I implement a or condition, suppose I want to retrieve the docs in which the tags contain either sports or eca

Comment: You could you query it using  `$in` :  
   `student.find( { tags: { $in : ["sports" , "eca"] } } )`